# Android ImageView over ImageView OnTouchListener

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

[image]

Well I have two imageviews and they look like this.
I want to add a TouchListener to just imageview1. but Listener not working properly.
I am adding imageview2 to

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

but not working again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It works for me correctly even when you click on imageview2. MainActivity onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("imageviewandontouchlistener", "imageView1 onTouch");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And in your Layout XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a custom `OnTouchListener` to `imageview2` that always returns **false** in the `onTouch` method. This way the touch event will be passed to the views bellow until one of them returns **true** in the `onTouch` method.